# How can I set the public folder write permission to the user www-data after deploying my laravel project in railway.app

Tags: laravel, permissions, railway

I need to change the permission of the public folder from my laravel project after deploying it to railway.app because the user needs to send images to the backend

i tried to solve it with docker run and chmod but does not work, I don`t know how (or if it is possible to access the server of railway to run a command)

Comment: `because the user needs to send images to the backend` <<<=== explain that one, please. So ... if railway.app = Docker, you might want to do it in the Dockerfile. Try also to enter the docker container with `docker-compose exec -it <id of docker container> /bin/bash`, with that you're in the container and you can then `chmod` or `chown` what you would like

Comment: what i meant about send images to backend is that the user can set an profile picture that is going to be stored in public

Comment: I am kind of new in the Docker world, can you elaborate better or send me some docs that might help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.